# If the number of features are much larger than the number of examples in dataset does svm still work?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, dimensionality-reduction

Linear regression doesn't work if the number of features is larger than the dataset size; unless regularization is applied. Does svm also have similar issues? Will it not give a good approximation if the number of examples are less in comparison to the dimensionality of features? Say if the examples are 1/10th or 1/100th of the features??

Comment: This question would be much more appropriate at [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). Though if you post there, it may end up being marked as duplicate, because a post list [this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35276/svm-overfitting-curse-of-dimensionality) should answer your question.

Answer (score -1):

When number of examples are less in comparison to number of features you would not have enough data to fit a non linear SVM i.e SVM with non linear kernel.A SVM with linear kernel(or without a kernel) is one way to go.

If you want to use a non linear SVM then you have to carefully choose the kernel parameters and Regularization parameters and tune them properly.

What I mean is that there is no inherent problem with using an SVM (or other regularised models) on a problem with hundreds of observations and thousands of attributes, provided the regularisation parameters are tuned properly.